# How can I obtain the "latitude and longitude" of the selected place with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to use Google Maps API service to allow my site visitors to type in their address in a box. Once he/she selects a matching address, I want to obtain the `latitude` and `longitude` info about the provided address.

Using the code in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), I got a map and a text box on my site. However, once Google finds a matching address I need to get the `latitude` and `longitude` info for the selected address only.

Here is the function that initialize the map

```
function initMap() {

    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397, 
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 6
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {

      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      console.log(places);
      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {

        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        /*
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };
        */


        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          //icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        //coords.latitude

        var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();  

        console.log(latitude, longitude);

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }

      });

      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });


}
```

The following lines of code gave me the info that I am looking for. However, it seems that it display's it more that once (possibly it is displaying the info for multiple addresses). How can I get the `latitude` and `longitude` info only one address?

```
   var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
   var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

I tried adding a click listener where I Can grab the info one the lick event like this

```
    map.addListener("click", function (event) {
        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
        var lng = event.latLng.lng();

        console.log(lat, lng);
    });
```

However, this gives me the `latitude` and `longitude` of the place where I click on the map, not the address that I selected from the text box after the autocomplete suggested the matching addresses

Comment: The `SearchBox.getPlaces()` method returns an array of matching places.  Please provide an example where you enter an address and get multiple results.  Perhaps you should use [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) rather than [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an easier way but I use maps.google.com and right-click wherever I want to find the coordinates for and choose *what's here?*, then the longitude and latitude will appear at the bottom of the map.

Comment: I need to obtain that info from a selected address. when i type an address google shows me a selection. from the selection I would choose an address. I want to obtain the info from that address

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google's API you can just send an AJAX request, you don't need a map on your page to get coordinates. Check this out!

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
var responseAsObject;
$("#div").load( "url", function( response, status, xhr ) {
responseAsObject = $.parseJSON(response);
});
var long = responseAsObject.results.geometry.location.lng;
var lat = responseAsObject.results.geometry.location.lat;
```

Comment: You can use the map to get the Address in it's human readable form and just use Google's API to get the coordinates in a JSON format!